# Spring Data REST Keycloak - Best way to secure REST endpoints?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-rest, keycloak

When securing a Spring Data REST application with keycloak the spring security allows to secure REST endpoints by making a configuration class extending `KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and overriding `configure(HttpSecurity)` as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class KeycloakSecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
          super.configure(http);
          http
          .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/customers/**").hasRole("view-customers")
          .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/customers/**").hasRole("create-customers")
          .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH, "/customers/**").hasRole("edit-customers")
          .anyRequest().authenticated();
            }
        }
```

But hard coding it like this makes difficult for future changes. Is there a better way to do this?